# Website gets unresponsive

Tags: dynamic-linking, broker, webforms

Most of the time website goes hanged, unresponsive. We are using Tridion WebForms and some user control having Broker query.

Tridion Version is: SDL Tridion 5.3

I have checked the Broker log and it shows below message:

**Error from : CD_Broker Log file**

```
ComponentPresentationFactory.getComponentPresentation(String, String) got invalid URIs as parameters
java.text.ParseException: URI string  does not start with tcm:
    at com.tridion.util.TCMURI.load(TCMURI.java:90)
    at com.tridion.util.TCMURI.<init>(TCMURI.java:76)
    at com.tridion.dcp.ComponentPresentationFactory.getComponentPresentation(ComponentPresentationFactory.java:146)
```

**Error from : CD_Webform Log file**

```
[Error] Error during processing session TWF_B1FD2C99DCD508DA73725176F4BA7FE130E06C4F
com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Error reading contents of xml file: formdata.xml for session TWF_B1FD2C99DCD508DA73725176F4BA7FE130E06C4F, Premature end of file., Premature end of file.
    at com.tridion.webforms.storage.FileSystemStorage.get(FileSystemStorage.java:193)
    at com.tridion.webforms.PersistenceManager.get(PersistenceManager.java:167)
    at com.tridion.webforms.PersistenceManagerImpl.forEachSession(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:233)
    at com.tridion.webforms.SessionProcessorManager$SessionProcessorRunnable.run(SessionProcessorManager.java:197)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Embedded exception:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.tridion.webforms.utils.XMLUtils.loadDocument(XMLUtils.java:80)
    at com.tridion.webforms.storage.FileSystemStorage.get(FileSystemStorage.java:189)
    at com.tridion.webforms.PersistenceManager.get(PersistenceManager.java:167)
    at com.tridion.webforms.PersistenceManagerImpl.forEachSession(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:233)
    at com.tridion.webforms.SessionProcessorManager$SessionProcessorRunnable.run(SessionProcessorManager.java:197)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I restart the Tridion services on web server, site starts working as usual.

Please help.

Comment: Can you supply a little more information, like does this happen all of the time with any webform, or only on a specific webform. What are the details of the webform (can you post its form XML) and how is the form added to the page and what target language are you using etc. etc.

Answer (score 5):

> **Error reading contents of xml file: formdata.xml for session TWF_B1FD2C99DCD508DA73725176F4BA7FE130E06C4F, Premature end of file., Premature end of file.**

It looks like above error causes due to the `formdata.xml` contains invalid XML.

So when it reaches to `getComponentPresentation`, function gets values as text and not the tcm id.

And also I suspect that:

- On `loadDocument`, you are calling `parse` function. Here you might be passing `StreamReader` as `empty` in some cases, which can leads to below error

> **org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.**

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be some logical error, as clearly visible in your message that  `ComponentPresentationFactory.getComponentPresentation(String, String)` is expecting both component and template prefixed with "tcm"

Have you checked this?

Comment: I have checked that all IDs are prefixed with "tcm:". finding where it is not properly created. thanks

Comment: check for both component and component template, thx

Answer (score 0):

As website failed to return the page sometime, now I am looking into database level and found that Tridion broker log (.ldf) size is more than 20 GB. and system disk space available only 2GB.

Comment: Looks like there should be some DB maintenance happening, that is not currently happening...